# How would water pool on a disc-shaped planet of Earth mass?

Tags: gravity, fluid-statics, planets

All this flat-earthism stuff is best ignored (although that is sometimes difficult) but it did get me wondering about the physics behind the pooling of water on a disc-shaped planet.  Not for the sake of arguing with the fools, you understand, just as a thought experiment.  (I know that disc-shaped planets would never naturally occur but let's say that some aliens built one out of unobtanium for the sake of argument).

Let's say that we want the top to have the same surface area as Earth (510 million km²) which means that it has a radius of 12,740 km, and a diameter of 25,480km.  Earth's volume is (approx) 1 e12 km3, so that means that the disc must be 1960 km thick (about 7% of the diameter).  It has the same mass as the Earth - approxc 6 e24 kg.  So, we have a planet that looks something like this:

[image: Discworld, elephants and turtles omitted for clarity]

Now, let's say, we deposit Earth's water in the middle of the top of this disc.  We ignore the effects of being in space, such as freezing, evaporating, sublimating etc and just think about the effect of gravity on the water.

My initial thought would be that it would form a dome which is effectively part of a sphere centred on the centre of gravity of the disc.  Something like this:

[image]

If we treat Earth's gravity as all "emanating" from a single point, then that is correct, I think.

However, in the case of a non-spherical body like this, then perhaps that isn't the case?  Or is it?  Would all of the extra mass spread along the length of the body make the water "spread out" more?

Is it changed if we make the disc much wider, and much thinner, but having the same mass?

Comment: When in an equilibrium configuration, the fluid settles such that its surface is equipotential with respect to the gravitational potential. So you just need to calculate the equipotential surfaces of this cylinder and find the one that contains the volume of the water (assuming it is incompressible). Luckily, someone has already calculated the gravitational potential of a cylinder. Check out [here](http://walter.bislins.ch/bloge/index.asp?page=Gravitational+Acceleration+and+Potential+Field+of+a+Cylinder). From those plots you may get an idea of the shape water would have.

Comment: @Prallax I couldn't do that myself but that page you link too looks useful, thanks.